# Usando ArrayList para fazer update das informação no c# "checkedlistbox"

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

Fala galera to com uma dificuldade em pegar minhas strings para atualizar as minhas informação.
o meu cenário é esse atualmente:
eu possuo um checkedlistbox onde tenho minhas strings no total sao 9. Na parte de inserção dos dados eu consigo fazer normalmente, porém nao sei como pegar a string selecionada e atualizar **OBS:MINHAS STRINGS SAO FIXAS TANTO PARA INSERÇÃO TANTO PARA UPDATE**.
se eu coloco meu checkedlistbox.text, ele pega somente uma string, mesmo eu selecionando mais de uma, já tentei checkedlistbox.setitems, CheckedItems e por ai vai. e na vdd eu preciso pegar mais de uma string selecionada e mandar para meu banco.

esse é meu codigo onde eu tenho meus campos para atualizar, eu ultilizei parametros por que acredito que seria mais fácil.

```
public bool Update(ArrayList p_arrUpdate)
        {
        vsql = "UPDATE alunos SET nome = @nome, idade = @idade, endereco = @endereco, quadra_lote = @quadra_lote, telefone = @telefone, email = @email, cidade = @cidade, uf = @uf, nome_pai = @nome_pai, nome_mae = @nome_mae, situacao = @situacao, atividade = @atividade  WHERE id_aluno = @id_aluno";

            SqlCommand objcmd = null;

            if (this.conectar())

                try // ele responsavel por tentar executar o array, se der alguma coisa errada e vai cair no finally
                {

                    objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id_aluno", p_arrUpdate[0]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nome", p_arrUpdate[1]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idade", p_arrUpdate[2]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@endereco", p_arrUpdate[3]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@quadra_lote", p_arrUpdate[4]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@telefone", p_arrUpdate[5]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", p_arrUpdate[6]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cidade", p_arrUpdate[7]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@uf", p_arrUpdate[8]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nome_pai", p_arrUpdate[9]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nome_mae", p_arrUpdate[10]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@situacao", p_arrUpdate[11]));
                    objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@atividade", p_arrUpdate[12]));


                objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return true;

                }
                catch (SqlException sqlerr)
                {

                    throw sqlerr;
                }
                finally
                {

                    this.desconectar();
                }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

esse é meu codigo onde no botao salvar as alteração ele faz o ArrayList.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SysDBADM obj = new SysDBADM();
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            arr.Add(TB_cod.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_nome.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_idade.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_endereco.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_quadra_lote.Text);
            arr.Add(MD_telefoneCel.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_email.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_cidade.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_uf.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_nomepai.Text);
            arr.Add(TB_nomemae.Text);
            arr.Add(CB_ativo.Text);
            arr.Add(CLB_atividade.Text + ","); // esse é meu checkedlistbox

            if (obj.Update(arr))
                {

                    TB_cod.Clear();
                    TB_nome.Clear();
                    TB_idade.Clear();
                    TB_endereco.Clear();
                    TB_quadra_lote.Clear();
                    MD_telefoneFixo.Clear();
                    MD_telefoneCel.Clear();
                    TB_email.Clear();
                    TB_cidade.Clear();
                    TB_uf.Clear();
                    TB_nomepai.Clear();
                    TB_nomemae.Clear();
                    CB_ativo.Text = "";


                    while (CLB_atividade.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    CLB_atividade.SetItemChecked(CLB_atividade.CheckedIndices[0],false);
                }
                   MessageBox.Show("Cadastro Atualizado.", "Mensagem do Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Erro ao Atualizar!", "Mesagem do Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
           }

        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(erro + "Erro Ocorrido");
        }

    }
```

essa é imagem onde eu faço as alteração do registro cadastrado.
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Substitua o seu `while` por este `foreach`

```
foreach (var item in CLB_atividade.CheckedItems)
{
  //item tem o valor checado                
}
```

Utilização do evento *ItemCheck*
[image: Evento ItemCheck]

Comment: bom dia @alexandre Cavaloti, entao a minha difuldade esta sendo em atualizar as informação conforme selecionadas, ou seja as informação já esta sendo gravadas quando eu faço inserção dos dados, o que eu to precisando e atualiza-las as informação por exemplo: no meu exemplo a minha imagem tem 2 opcao selecionadas que foi  feita na hora do meu insert, o que eu preciso e fazer o update, ou seja se eu clicar em outra atividade ou remover e clicar no botao salvar alteracao , essas informação que te atualizar.

Comment: Entendi, ou seja, você precisa saber os itens que foram desmarcados também. Isso pode ser feito utilizando o evento _ItemCheck_ do checkbox. Adicionei na resposta uma imagem que contem os valores passados para esse evento, que são: Item checado ou "deschecado", index do item, valor antigo e valor novo. Pode utilizar este evento para controlar os itens que devem ser retirados e os itens que devem ser colocados na lista no BD.

Comment: entendi sua explicacao, dei uma pesquisada na documentação da microsoft. so nao sei como implementar isso dentro do meu codigo é a primeira vez que uso o checkedlistbox, nao tenho muita experiencia com c#, por isso to pedindo ajuda. mais vamos lah resolver esse problema. dentro do meu arr.add(checkedlistbox.itemCheck); devo fazer isso ?

Comment: Como estão no banco de dados, os dados das atividades, que deve inserir ou fazer o update/delete?

Comment: a forma como está sendo inserida no banco é minha tabela chamada Alunos, na coluna ativade. uso o meu checkedlistbox para pegar as strings do collections, e concatenar de acordo com item selecionado na hora do cadastramento, e no meu form de update como esta na imagem eu uso a mesma tabela alunos para fazer o update mais no meu codigo eu consigo fazer o update das informação dos meus textbox, e combobox, mais nao sei como fazer com o checkedlistbox

Comment: ou seja, todas as atividades concatenadas?

Comment: sim e armazenadas na minha coluna atividades

Comment: Então sempre faça update das atividades que estão selecionadas, independente se houver alteração ou não. Isso resolve o problema certo?

Comment: sim as atividades sao fixas no meu checkedlistbox, o que eu preciso e fazer o update das informação que foram inseridas na hora do cadastro, ou seja quando o usuario selecionar 3 atividades e na hora do cadastramento na hora que eu for editar ele vai me mostrar as 3 tividades que é o que ele esta fazendo, mais eu preciso editar ou seja se eu precisar tirar uma atividade do cadastro que foi realizado tera que atualizar para 2 atividades apenas entendeu

Comment: só atualizar sempre tudo. Pois sendo uma linha concatenada com todas as atividades selecionadas. Exemplo: Atividades: Pilates; Zumba .  UPDATE: Atividades = Zumba; Yoga